# Как периодически ставить задани в очередь вместо их выполнения

Tags: python, celery

Можно ли как-то с помощью `celery` не выполнять задания через каждые x секунд, а отправлять их в очередь, чтобы одно задание ждало пока не закончится другое? Но чтобы добавление происходило каждые x секунд?

В таком варианте ожидания не происходит и задания выполняются одновременно

```py
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10), name='task_1')
def task_1():
    time.sleep(7)
    print(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} Задание 1 закончено')


@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10), name='task_2')
def task_2():
    time.sleep(7)
    print(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} Задание 2 закончено')
```

Comment: Использовать класс `threading.Queue`?

Comment: @0andriy celery выполняет задания вообще в другом процессе, часто даже на другом сервере..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как celery использует multiprocessing для выполнения заданий, Вы можете использовать `multiprocessing.Semaphore([value])` для того чтоб притормозить выполнение заданий.

```
import multiprocessing

sema = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10), name='task_1')
def task_1():
    sema.acquire()
    time.sleep(7)
    print(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} Задание 1 закончено')
    sema.release()


@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10), name='task_2')
def task_2():
    sema.acquire()
    time.sleep(7)
    print(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} Задание 2 закончено')
    sema.release()
```

Но в данном случае очередь продолжит набиваться так как вторая задача будет выполняться 14 секунд.

Comment: Спасибо, может еще подскажете как настроить логгирование селери в файл?

Comment: целели использует обычный логер через import logging

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file
вот так попробуй настроить обычный логер, если не получится -

вот тут смотри в конце сигнал https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#logging

на сигнале получи логер и перенастрой